# Google BigQuery -Revert to the old table view in BigQuery WEB UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

I work with a lot of structured data and repeated fields in my tables, the new and "improved" table UI makes viewing this data extremely difficult, with everything collapsed by default.

Is there a way to revert to the older row based table views? If not, is there a way to make expanded as the default behaviour?

also open to suggestions for alternate IDEs.

Comment: Try Goliath - BigQuery IDE, part of Potens.io suite of BigQuery Tools. Few links to get it - [Google Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/potens-io/potensio), [Potens.io](https://potens.io/), [Potens.io Knowledgebase](https://potensio.zendesk.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MikhailBerlyant try using the following tools:

> Try Goliath - BigQuery IDE, part of Potens.io suite of BigQuery Tools.
> Few links to get it -  [Google Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/potens-io/potensio), [Potens.io](https://potens.io/),
> [Potens.io Knowledgebase](https://potensio.zendesk.com/)

As of this writing you can still use "Disable Editor Tab" to use old UI of BQ. This is available until (2022-04-11) this date is subject to change based on received feedbacks. Using the old UI, it shows the repeated results in an expanded manner by default.

There is already an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/227159963) for this UI issue about the collapsed results and the BigQuery Engineering team is aware of it. I suggest to ["star" the issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) to let the team know that this is an important request.